# Why is npm showing ERR! code EPERM when trying to install eslint dependencies in my local project folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint, git-bash

[The error stack shown in the git bash terminal of Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYlw5.png) (image is a link because I am new to stack overflow with low reputation)

I've been trying to configure eslint for a local project and so far **npm i -D eslint** has worked. However **./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init** brings me to installing the **dependencies** and that's where it causes problems. It seems there are some **permission issues** and it's giving ***npm ERR! code EPERM***.

Things I've tried:

1. Restarting machine
2. Using windows terminal as administrator
3. Closing/reopening VScode
4. Using git bash outside of VScode terminal

What can I do to allow permission for the operation?

The error messages make it clear that it is likely not an error from NPM itself but rather the files and their accessibility.

Comment: have you tried running it in your terminal and not vs code?

Comment: @about14sheep I did and it worked! But for some reason the current version of ESlint doesn't work with the airbnb dependency files, so I had to install ESlint@7.2